# moving a map overlay

Tags: iphone, maps, overlay, drag

I am trying to create an app where the user can mark an area on a map. I want him to be able to move the area he marked.

I found that there is an api for adding overlays on a map, but I cannot get to move those overlays once I put them on the map. I tried to subclass the MKCircleView with my own view and implement the touchesBegan:withEvent: method but it never seems to get called.

Any ideas how this can be implemented and why it doesn't work this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking through the apple developer code for sample called Regions.
It has circles which can be dragged and moved around.